# Understanding AWS lambda retry mechanism

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My use case :
From the spring-boot application, I am publishing a payload to AWS SNS, this SNS is triggering the Lambda function.

If the lambda function fails, is there any configuration available on AWS lambda where we can specify the number of retries and the duration after which each retry happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you can't control [retry policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#delivery-policies-for-protocols) as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#delivery-policies-for-protocols):

> With the exception of HTTP/S, you **can't change Amazon SNS-defined delivery policies**.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html specifies the retry policies for Lambda in case the Lambda service itself is unavailable.

| Immediate retry (no delay) phase | Pre-backoff phase | Backoff phase | Post-backoff phase | Total attempts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 times, without delay | 2 times, 1 second apart | 10 times, with exponential backoff, from 1 second to 20 seconds | 100,000 times, 20 seconds apart | 100,015 times, over 23 days |

And also notes

> With the exception of HTTP/S, you can't change Amazon SNS-defined delivery policies. Only HTTP/S supports custom policies. See Creating an HTTP/S delivery policy.

Therefore **no**, you cannot change the retry behaviour of SNS for Lambda invocations.

There are however two things you can do:

- you can subscribe an SQS queue to SNS and then let you lambda get triggered by that queue. On SQS you can configure the retry behaviour to some extent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/sqs-retries.html .
- you can change the async invocation configuration on the lambda and set the number of retries between 0 and 2. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-errors